# Vue + Vuex: format input data

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

Inspired from several example, I'm trying to write a custom component that formats it's value with a specific method.

Here's the component:

```
<template>
  <input
    type="text"
    v-model="inputValue"
  />
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  import {formatPhoneNumber} from '~/utils/string';

  export default {
    computed: {
      inputValue: {
        get() {
          return formatPhoneNumber(this.value)
        },
        set(value) {
          this.$emit('input', formatPhoneNumber(value))
        }
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

I'm using Vuex, and I call the component this way in the parent component:

```
<PhoneInput :value="cellPhoneNumber" class="input" @input="addCellPhoneNumber" />

  computed: {
    cellPhoneNumber() {
      return this.$store.state.identity.cellPhoneNumber;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addCellPhoneNumber: function(phoneNumber) {
      this.$store.commit('identity/addCellPhoneNumber', phoneNumber)
    },
  }
```

The `set` part works, it goes to the store, but the data comes back to the component, `cellPhoneNumber` is called, but not `inputValue#get`.

Since it might be related to the fact that I use `@input/:value` in the parent component, I tried to use it also on it's child component:

```
<template>
  <input
    @input="formatValue"
    type="text"
    :value="formattedValue"
  />
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  import {formatPhoneNumber} from '~/utils/string';

  export default {
    computed: {
      formattedValue: function(){
        return formatPhoneNumber(this.value)
      },
    },
    methods: {
      formatValue(e) {
        this.$emit('input', formatPhoneNumber(e.target.value))
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Without success, the same thing happens.

Can someone tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: You're missing a `prop` definition in the component that expects`this.value`, so it's not reactive.

Comment: Great! Thanks I thought `props` were optional, simply adding constraints or warnings instead of having a real behavioral impact.

Comment: I do wish that aspect of Vue was a bit more intuitive, or at least gave more information than what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ohgodwhy mentioned in the comments:

> You're missing a `prop` definition in the component that expects `this.value`, so it's not reactive.